# Prepend line that contains {} in files recursively using find and sed

Tags: sed, files, find

I want to prepend recursively all files ending with `.ts` with this text: `export {};` and I need to exclude at least the folder `node_modules`.

I tried:

```
find . f ! -path '*/node_modules/*' -iname "*.ts" -exec sed -e '1 i\export {}' \;
```

Result: for each file I get: `sed: 1: "1 i\export ./src/query/ ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`

Update:
I installed `gnu-sed` on macOS and tried using `gsed` as well. But it doesn't seem to work - it seems to run infinitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to:

> The string `'{}'` is replaced by the *current file  name*  being 
>   processed
>                 everywhere  it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.
>                 Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\`) or quoted to protect them from  expansion  by  the 
>   shell.

Use the following approach:

```
find . -type f ! -path '*/node_modules/*' -iname "*.ts" -exec sed -i '1 i\export\{\}' {} \;
```

`-i`, `--in-place` - `sed` option for editing files in place

Comment: When using `gsed` instead of `sed` (because of macOS) it did work, thanks.